# Are there any available desktop tools which allow users to get popup notifications when certain actions happened on sharepoint sites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, installation, notifications

i am searching for a desktop tool which integrate with sharepoint on-premises 2013,and allow users to define the activities they want to receive notification on. and then when an action happened a popup will be shown on the user desktop that the following action has happen. something similar to the user popups for skype for business.. so i as a user can say that i want to be notified (similar to the user notification module) when an item is added to this list, or when someone assign an item to me, etc..

then while i am working on my desktop a popup dialog will appear from the desktop tool that certain action have been executed...
not sure if this is something that are available for sharepoint ?
Thanks